# Save data from a Complex View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to MVC and want to make sure I understand how to appreach a complex view I need to build.

I need to allow the user to add multiple Institutions on a page and each Institution can

have multiple trainings.

so the view model would be a list of institutions which contains a list of Trainings.

I will have a button that allows them to add multiple institutions and within the institution

section another button that will allow them to add multiple trainings.

On the postback method  Do I simply loop through the institutions in the model 
and for each institution loop through it's list of trainings to save them to the database?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to instead use a Controller like this:

```
public class InstitutionController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View(); // Keep it simple, load data via JSON instead
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Load()
    {
        // Go get Institutions etc
        return Json(institutions);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Save(Institutions[] institutions)
    {
        try
        {
            // Save the institutions to the DB
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Message = "Error." });
        }
        return Json(null); // Or some other way of saying it worked
    }
}
```

That is, the Model you pass to the View is not persisted by the browser - instead it's briefly in server memory while the server generates a response.

In the example above however, you can create a View that uses for example jquery to load the Model from the server via JSON, which you can then persist in the browser for the life of the page. When the user makes a modification to an Institution or Instutions you can use a method like Save() above to send the new data or data changes to the server to be saved to the database.